# angular chosen not closing after selecting option

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, angular-chosen

I am using angular chosen to spice up my select options, And all is good and well.
But when I try to put it inside a modal selecting one of the options closes the modal, but `chosen` stays open.

Tried using: `backdrop: 'static',` in my modal. same thing.

> The Chosen select:

```
<select chosen ng-model="fullMember.Master_record"
               ng-init="loadMembers()" 
               ng-options="Member.FullName for Member in Members" 
               class="form-control"
               inherit-select-classes="true"
               search-contains="true"
               max-shown-results="10"
               no-results-text="':אין_נתונים'"
               placeholder-text-single="':בחר'">
                  <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

> The Modal Factory.

```
return {
  animationsEnabled: true,
  open: function (sub, MID) {
    var out = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: "views/modals/" + sub.click + ".html",
      controller: "ModalInstanceController",
      size: 'lg',
      resolve: {
        MID: function () {
          return MID;
        }
      },
      backdrop: 'static',
    });

    return (out.result);
  }
```

Is there something I am missing?

P.S. no errors, just looking ugly..
[image]

Comment: Can you use ngChange() to close your modal? What modal are you using it?

Comment: @LeoCaseiro I don't want the modal to close. I want it to stay since I am choosing just one field.

It is the Chosen that I want to close.

I am using the $uibModal from angular ui bootstrap